# Best Apache Configuration

Tags: apache, download

Please, Can you help me for best Apache Configuration

I own the servers for files download, Download files by direct links

ex: `domain.com/files.rar`

Without programming or php function

The problem: Sometimes I having a high load or stop servers

For this can you help me for best Apache Configuration

```
Such as: 
Server Limit 
Max Clients  
Max Requests Per Child 
Keep-Alive 
Keep-Alive Timeout 
Max Keep-Alive Requests 
Etc.
```

My servers with 4GB RAM and HDD drives, and 100Mb-ps and 1GBMb-ps

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Separate Static and Dynamic Content**

Use separate servers for static and dynamic content. Apache processes serving dynamic content will carry overhead and swell to the size of the content being served, never decreasing in size. Each process will incur the size of any loaded PHP or Perl libraries. A 6MB-30MB process size [or 10% of server's memory] is not unusual, and becomes a waist of resources for serving static content.

For a more efficient use of system memory, either use mod_proxy to pass specific requests onto another Apache Server, or use a lightweight server to handle static requests:

> ```
> Nginx
> lighttpd
> Or use a front-end caching proxy such as Squid-Cache or Varnish-Cache
> ```

The Server handling the static content goes up front.

Note that configuration settings will be quite different between a dynamic content Server and a static content Server.
mod_deflate

Reduce bandwidth by 75% and improve response time by using mod_deflate.

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
<Location />
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css text/xml application/x-javascript
</Location>
```

**Loaded Modules**

Reduce memory footprint by loading only the required modules.
Some also advise to statically compile in the needed modules, over building DSOs (Dynamic Shared Objects). Very bad advice. You will need to manually rebuild Apache every time a new version or security advisory for a module is put out, creating more work, more build related headaches, and more downtime.

**mod_expires**

Include mod_expires for the ability to set expiration dates for specific content; utilizing the 'If-Modified-Since' header cache control sent by the user's browser/proxy. Will save bandwidth and drastically speed up your site for [repeat] visitors.

Note that this can also be implemented with mod_headers.

**KeepAlive**

Enable HTTP persistent connections to improve latency times and reduce server load significantly [25% of original load is not uncommon].

prefork MPM:

```
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 2
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
```

worker and winnt MPMs:

```
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 15
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
```

With the prefork MPM, it is recommended to set 'KeepAlive' to 'Off'. Otherwise, a client will tie up an entire process for that span of time. Though in my experience, it is more useful to simply set the 'KeepAliveTimeout' value to something very low [2 seconds seems to be the ideal value]. This is not a problem with the worker MPM [thread-based], or under Windows [which only has the thread-based winnt MPM].

With the worker and winnt MPMs, the default 15 second timeout is setup to keep the connection open for the next page request; to better handle a client going from link to link. Check logs to see how long a client remains on each page before moving on to another link. Set value appropriately [do not set higher than 60 seconds].

**SymLinks**

Make sure **'Options +FollowSymLinks -SymLinksIfOwnerMat**ch' is set for all directories. Otherwise, Apache will issue an extra system call per filename component to substantiate that the filename is NOT a symlink; and more system calls to match an owner.

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

**AllowOverride**

Set a default 'AllowOverride None' for your filesystem. Otherwise, for a given URL to path translation, Apache will attempt to detect an .htaccess file under every directory level of the given path.

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

**ExtendedStatus**

If mod_status is included, make sure that directive 'ExtendedStatus' is set to 'Off'. Otherwise, Apache will issue several extra time-related system calls on every request made.

```
ExtendedStatus Off
Timeout
```

Lower the amount of time the server will wait before failing a request.
Timeout 45

Answer (score 0):

If you are having load-problems with your apache setup, you could also consider migrating to another system. From my personal experience I would suggest you to try nginx to serve static files.

Comment: Nginx does not support .htaccess, for this must use Apache,  and I need best Apache Configuration